# Proof with $\Theta$

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing

I am having a hard time proving the following statement:

> Suppose that the functions $f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2 : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}\ are \ such \ that \ f_1 \in \Theta (g_1) \ and \ f_2 \in \Theta (g_2).$
>
> Prove that $(f_1 + f_2) \in \Theta (max[g_1, g_2])$
>
> Here $(f_1 + f_2)(n) = f_1(n) + f_2(n) \ and \ max[g_1, g_2](n) = max [g_1(n), g_2(n)].$

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y \ge 0$, then $\max\{x,y\} \le x+y \le 2\max\{x,y\}$.