# Proving the sum of two functions is $\Theta$ of the max of those functions?

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose that the functions $\ f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ (set of real numbers greater or equal to 0) are such that $\ f_1 \in \Theta \ (g_1)$ and $\ f_2 \in \Theta \ (g_2)$.

Prove that $ \ f_1 + f_2 \in \Theta (\max\{\ g_1, g_2\})$

I have no idea how to go about this proof. Could someone please explain?

Thank you!

Comment: Write down the definition of $f_1\in\theta(g_1)$ and $g_2\in\theta(g_2)$ and see if you can do something with $f_1 + f_2$.

Comment: I gave a hint here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582810/proof-with-theta/582829#582829